# how to show hidden content with PHP session when users are logged in

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, session

I want to hide some content at my index.php which should be accessible only if the user is logged in. I got some code i learnt so far here:

`if(isset($_POST['logged']{echo "welcome " ;} else{include "login_form.php";}`

I have no clue what is "logged" inside my conditional statement here.I would be grateful if someone help me out . thanks

Comment: You should look into [PHP Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Comment: Thanks for your kind response, can you please tell me, what the "logged" term represents that i have shown it in my code ` $_POST['**logged**'] ` ; inside the conditional statement . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use sessions for this or even cookies if you want to remember user's login.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
  echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
} else {
   echo "Please log in first to see this page.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro it's helpful  . But can you please tell me what the' loggedin '  term represents for ? is that belongs to any div ?

Comment: represent a session variable. This's PHP and PHP doesn't have divs.

Comment: simple tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp